# Python pass in variable assignments through a function wrapper

Tags: python, variables, function, argument-passing

So I know that you can wrap a function around another function by doing the following.

```
def foo(a=4,b=3):
   return a+b
def bar(func,args):
   return func(*args)
```

so if I then called

```
bar(foo,[2,3])
```

the return value would be 5.

I am wondering is there a way to use bar to call foo with foo(b=12) where bar would return 16?

Does this make sense?  Thank you so much for your time ahead of time! And sorry for asking so many questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This requires the [`**kwargs` (keyword arguments)](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) syntax.

```
def foo(a=4, b=3):
    return a+b
def bar(func, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

print bar(foo, b=12) # prints 16
```

Where `*args` is any number of positional arguments, `**kwargs` is all the named arguments that were passed in.

And of course, they are only `*args` and `**kwargs` by convention; you could name them `*panda` and `**grilled_cheese` for all Python cares.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, you can also pass a dict in addition to (or instead of) the list:

```
def bar(func, args=[], kwargs={}):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

bar(foo, {'b':12})
```